# 3D effect with image as a background of another image

Tags: html, css, 3d, background-image

I'm trying to add a 3D effect to an image, the final result should look
like the following: (illustrated in Photoshop)

[image: the result i'm looking for]

I've tried playing with the css3 property `box-shadow`
but it doesn't provide a real 3D effect, as you can see in the following image:
(I know I can set blur to 0 and change sides, but as you can see - there's a difference in the **corners** between what I'm trying to achieve to the `box-shadow` result)

[image: the box-shadow result]

After not finding a only-CSS solution - I've created the following image and set it as a background of the image itself.

[image: the frame - image's background]

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/V47Ja/)**
* Please notice - I'm using the bootstrap framework.

**HTML**

```
<img src="" class="img-responsive framed">
```

**CSS**

```
.framed{
background-image: url('URL-OF-THE-FRAME');
padding-left: 5px; //The thickness of the "line"
padding-bottom: 5px; //The thickness of the "line"
background-size: cover;
}

.img-responsive{
display: block;
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
}
```

Which gives the result I was looking for - but,
if you re-size the window (try enlarging the result's window in the jsfiddle)
a distance between the image and the frame is being created.

[image: on resize - a distance is being created]

Should I try another tactic or am I missing here something?

Comment: I think this should be on http://ux.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I thought about it but it says: `User Experience Stack Exchange is ... for user experience researchers and experts.`. My question is not about "research" - it's a more of a coding problem. If more members think I should post there and not here - I'll close this one and re-post it over there.

Comment: It depends on your question, which I'm not clear on. Are you asking is this the best approach to this UI or I'm trying to do this and it's not working?

Comment: I think it's the statements *What's your opinion?....Should I try another tactic or am I missing here something?* which are confusing me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use percent padding so it addapts to the size of the image/container when window is resized.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/V47Ja/1/)**

*CSS :*

```
.framed{
    background-image: url('http://www.6pix.co/images/shadow-3.png');  
    padding-left: 2.9%;  
    padding-bottom: 2.9%;  
    background-size: cover;  
}
```

Comment: Seems great :) May I ask how you've reached the `2.9%` value? what was your calculation?

Comment: @OfirBaruch in fact I didn't calculate, I tried and found that value was hidding the white gap well. But if you want to make calculations, you can do : `%padding = (width of border / total width)*100 `

Comment: So since I'm using bootstrap, I should use js to achieve it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: no, you can just add the 2.9% padding instead of the 5px padding as you did in your fiddle.

Comment: But the total width would change according to the screen resolution. Or when you mentioned `total width` you meant the total width of the frame's image?

Comment: yes but as the padding is set in percentage, it adapts to the image size. As the image adapts to the screen size, the padding also adapts to the scrteen size.

Comment: Oh - you're right!! I got it.
I learned a new approach today thanks to you.